# simpl-schema dependency issues with meteor and iron cli

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, iron-router

A fresh new setup of 
`iron create project` and after adding the following packages

`iron add aldeed:collection2`
`iron add aldeed:simple-schema`
`iron add twbs:bootstrap`

I set up some controllers and collections and also edited the router.js file.
Then running a `iron run`
i got a long essay of errors but i was able to pick out from the errors that i have  a dependency is missing which was `simpl-schema`, I have tried to install it my running

`meteor npm install --save simpl-schema`

it was successful 
but i still get errors that `simpl-schema` is missing.

If you can help check into the errors and prescribe what next to do.

**Errors:**

https://pastebin.com/mE8cHjNk

Comment: You must only use the npm package of `simpl-schema`, remove the `aldeed:simple-schema`, dont hesitate to check the documentation of collection2